# Adding context device browser info in a Custom Event

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm sending via Raw Telemetric a Custom Event, but I would like to have the browser of the user that is sending the info.

```
        TelemetryClient telemetryAccount = new TelemetryClient();     
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {{"StackOverflowUserName", "Mario Levrero" }};
        telemetryAccount.TrackEvent("MyCustomEvent", properties);
```

I see from the [Application Insights Export Data Model Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-data-model/) that there are some properties related to the context, like `context.device.browserVersion` but it says that:

> Context All types of telemetry are accompanied by a context section.
>   **Not all of these fields are transmitted** with every data point.

I'm receiving the Event info with data about the context like:

- Device.Type
- Device.RoleInstance

But I'm not receiving the `context.device.browserVersion` How can I force to send other properties of the `context`, as `device.browser` that are not being sent?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the .NET AppInsights SDK to track telemetry, which by default sends RequestTelemetry data and, even with the custom event, the context information does not include browser information.

Have you tried including the [JavaScript SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-web-track-usage) to track page views? In my application, I see browser context information for PageView telemetry (and any custom events sent using that SDK).